# What are # and : used for in Qbasic?

Tags: legacy-code, qbasic

I have a legacy code doing math calculations. It is reportedly written in QBasic, and runs under VB6 successfully. I plan to write the code into a newer language/platform. For which I must first work backwards and come up with a detailed algorithm from existing code.

The problem is I can't understand syntax of few lines:

```
Dim a(1 to 200) as Double
Dim b as Double
Dim f(1 to 200) as Double
Dim g(1 to 200) as Double

For i = 1 to N
 a(i) = b: a(i+N) = c
 f(i) = 1#: g(i) = 0#
 f(i+N) = 0#: g(i+N) = 1#
Next i
```

Based on my work with VB5 like 9 years ago, I am guessing that a, f and g are Double arrays indexed from 1 to 200. However, I am completely lost about this use of # and : together inside the body of the for-loop.

Comment: I wonder if it should be worrying than the only non-constant right hand sides are `b` and `c`, which aren't initialized anywhere (and thus are 0).

Comment: The : symbol separates Basic statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`:` is the line continuation character, it allows you to chain multiple statements on the same line. `a(i) = b: a(i+N) = c` is equivalent to:

```
a(i)=b
a(i+N)=c
```

`#` is a type specifier. It specifies that the number it follows should be treated as a double.

Comment: Thanks a lot Blindy and sidran32!

Comment: Please be sure to vote up helpful answers and mark one of them as the solution. Thanks, and you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't programmed in QBasic for a while but I did extensively in highschool. The # symbol indicates a particular data type. It is to designate the RHS value as a floating point number with double precision (similar to saying 1.0f in C to make 1.0 a single-precision float). The colon symbol is similar to the semicolon in C, as well, where it delimits different commands. For instance:

```
a(i) = b: a(i+N) = c
```

is, in C:

```
a[i] = b; a[i+N] = c;
```